# When to declare a new (anonymous)function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit confused in how functions operate in javascript. I understand that they're all objects but how does that change how I would use them as arguments?

For instance, if I'm trying to use a callback function where the 2nd argument is evaluated after 1000ms...

```
$(this).fadeIn(1000,function(){alert('done fading in');});
```

Why can't I achieve the same effect with:

```
$(this).fadeIn(1000,alert('done fading in'));
```

If I do, it evaluates both at the same time. That is, (this) element fades in and the alert pops up at the same time.

When I'm calling alert(arg), aren't I creating a new object which gets passed into fadeIn()?

How exactly does this work?

Comment: good question. I'll stick around for this one

Comment: For the language nerds: The technique you want is called *[partial function application][1]*, also often called *Currying*. You effectively want a new function where some arguments are fixed, and others are not.

  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application

Comment: @nd: No, that's not really it. There is no currying or partial evaluation going on in the example. If you are looking for a term, *anonymous function* is it. Also *higher order functions* for functions that take functions as arguments.

Comment: @KaptajnKold You are right - but I read the question that randomafk assumed that alert('done fading in') would return a curried function (which it doesn't). I hope that I haven't increased the general confusion of the OP.

Comment: @nd: Currying actually does exist in EcmaScript 5. You could do this: `$(this).fadeIn(1000, alert.bind(window, "done fading in"))`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In this

```
 $(this).fadeIn(1000,alert('done fading in'));
```

what does fadeIn() see as its second argument? It's the result of calling

```
 alert('done fading in')
```

we are making the call to alert() **before** calling fadeIn().

In this case

```
$(this).fadeIn(1000,function(){alert('done fading in');});
```

we have an object

```
 function(){alert('done fading in');}
```

which fadeIn() calls at the right time.

Answer (score 5):

When you write:

```js
$(this).fadeIn(1000,alert('done fading in'));
```

you call function called alert immadiately by putting function name and parentheses after this name. And to fadeIn the result of this call is passed - this is undefined, because alert returns always undefined.

When you write

```js
$(this).fadeIn(1000,function(){alert('done fading in');});
```

you create a function object that and pass this function object to fadeIn. So after fadeIn is done it can call this function.

It is the same as:

```js
// create function
var callback = function () { alert('done fading in'); };
// and pass this function to fadeIn
$(this).fadeIn(1000, callback);
```

but when you write:

```js
var callback = alert('done fading in');
$(this).fadeIn(1000, callback);
```

then you will call alert immadiately and pass to fadeIn value which alert returns - undefined.

Answer (score 2):

In the first line the second parameter is a method. And in the second line its a method call.

you could also write it like this

```
function fadeInCallback() {
    alert('done fading in');
}

$(this).fadeIn(1000, fadeInCallback);
```

So what we do is that we pass in a reference to the fadeInCallback so the jQuery fadeIn function can call fadeInCallback once it's done with the fading.

The second line will execute

```
alert('done fading in');
```

before executeing the jQuery fadeIn function